# Sequence of execution in for loop / recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I only recently learned about jquery/javascript, and I am facing the following problem.

I am trying to control the sequence of function calls in a nested loop and/or recursion in jquery/javascript. It seems to me now that all functions are called almost simultaneously and do not follow the order in the code as I am used to in other programming languages, such as R. In an R script the code will not process the next line as long as the current line of code is unfinished. But it seems that the jquery code is firing all my getJSON requests simultaneously, and processes the results as soon as 1 result becomes available. It does not pay attention to the order of the getJSON calls. Is this true, or am I missing something? Refreshing the page below a couple of time gives me result sets in different orders, whereas the same order would be expected, time after time...

To explain the above I have created the following workable code, which uses the api of gridpointweather.com for illustration purposes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!--Body-->
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>

<!--Load jquery + uri.js-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.17.0/URI.min.js"></script>

<script>
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // GLOBAL VARIABLES.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var g_asLoc =                         ["24", "42", "19"];
    var g_asWeather =                     [];

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function getWeatherInfo(location, offset){    
        console.log("Location: " + location);
        console.log("Offset: " + offset);
        var sUrl = 'http://api.gridpointweather.com/weather/getjson?location=' + location + '%2C-72&model=gfs.api0.n7m4csjf3x2s92ic&hours=24&inunits=1&interptype=2&offset=' + offset;
        var requestUrl = sUrl;
        $.getJSON(requestUrl, function(data) {
            try {
                console.log("Data for location " + location, data);
            }catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            // Store something.
            $.each(data.data, function(index, weatherInfo){
                g_asWeather.push("Object " + index + ", Location: " + location + ", rawdate: " + weatherInfo.rawdate + ", Temp: " + weatherInfo.temp + "<br>");
            });

            // Offset with 25 if condition not met.
            if(offset == -25){
                // Display in #results.
                g_asWeather.push("<br><br>");
                $("#results").html(g_asWeather.join('\n'));
                console.log("Finished for location " + location);
                return;
            }else{
                console.log("Running again using offset " + (offset-25) + " for location " + location);
                getWeatherInfo(location, offset - 25);
            }
        }).error(function(){
                console.log("JSON error!");
                return;
        });
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // MAIN
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var iCounter = 0;
    while(iCounter < 2){
        for(iLoc=0; iLoc<g_asLoc.length; iLoc++){
            getWeatherInfo(g_asLoc[iLoc], 0);
        }
        iCounter = iCounter + 1;
    }
</script>
```

Preferably I would want the code to call the function getWeatherInfo for 1 location, and then finish the recursion for this location before proceeding with the next location... The order of the recursion is also important, as results from offset=0 should be in g_asWeather, before the results of offset=25. After finishing all locations the code should wait, say 1000 ms, before increasing iCounter with 1 and repeat the for loop while iCounter < 2. To summarize the result set should contain: iCounter=0, location 24, offset=0, offset=-25, location 42, offset=0, offset=-25, location 19, offset=0, offset=-25, wait 1000ms, iCounter=1, location 24, offset=0, offset=-25 etc etc while iCounter < 2.

Much appreciated.

Comment: The while and for loops are synchronous (happen in order) HOWEVER a couple statements within the `getWeatherInfo` function are asynchronous (happen out of order). Here is a [very basic primer](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/) on sync vs async javascript. More specifically, the `$.getJSON` and `$.each` functions are both asynchronous. Basically, as soon as the parser gets to the `$.getJSON` function, the getWeatherInfo function returns and the next iteration of the for loop continues.

Comment: This is why we have promises. Makes working with async program flow easy.

Comment: @MichaelL. that was helpfull to understand why this behavior occurs. But I have to make sure that everything within the for loop happens synchronously. The order of the locations does not really bother me, as long as the location information of a particular location (including its offset) are clustered. Any idea how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, the AJAX requests are asynchronous so you don't know in which order is going to end each one. What you can do is create an array to save the information and use the index of the for loop to have the data ordered, for example, instead of doing this:

```
 g_asWeather.push("Object " + index + ", Location: " + location + ", rawdate: " + weatherInfo.rawdate + ", Temp: " + weatherInfo.temp + "<br>");
```

You could do something like that (passing the iLoc as parameter):

```
 g_asWeather[iLoc] = "Object " + index + ", Location: " + location + ", rawdate: " + weatherInfo.rawdate + ", Temp: " + weatherInfo.temp + "<br>");
```

So your array will be ordered by the location, if you want to order your array in some other way, just change the variable where it is going to be stored the string.

Comment: I need to force the order of execution. I think your solution may work, but then I have to administrate for which iCounter the function was called. This may work, although the asynchronous request make me a little anxious. Isn't there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You can do something like that, I used a forEach, instead of the traditional for, to imrprove the readability. Also added setTimeout to the wait for the execution http://jsbin.com/memiwigezo/edit?html,js,output
I did not found a more elegant way of do it, remind that you are forcing to have the order of an asynchronous task

Comment: I have accepted this answer, as your example helped me to get what I wanted in a rather straightforward manner. The build-in waiting period doesn't work though. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To re-reiterate and expand on my comment:
The while and for loops are synchronous (happen in order) HOWEVER a couple statements within the `getWeatherInfo` function are asynchronous (happen out of order). Here is a [very basic primer](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/) on sync vs async javascript. More specifically, the `$.getJSON` and `$.each` functions are both asynchronous. Basically, as soon as the parser gets to the `$.getJSON` function, the `getWeatherInfo` function returns and the next iteration of the for loop continues. Similarly, all the iterations of the `$.each` function are fired off 'all at once' (not technically true, but conceptually) and can complete in any order.

> The order of the locations does not really bother me, as long as the
>   location information of a particular location (including its offset)
>   are clustered. Any idea how I can make this happen?

I would recommend altering your data structure and making g_asWeather an object (`var g_asWeather = {};` instead of `var g_asWeather = [];`) with locations as properties. Your $.each loop would look something like this:

```
// Store something.
$.each(data.data, function(index, weatherInfo){
    g_asWeather[location] = "Object " + index + ", Location: " + location + ", rawdate: " + weatherInfo.rawdate + ", Temp: " + weatherInfo.temp + "<br>";
});
```

To output the results, something like:

```
var results = '';
for (var location in g_asWeather) {
    // This check is used because of some non-obvious ways that JavaScript can treat
    // objects. http://phrogz.net/death-to-hasownproperty explains both why to 
    // use it and why not to. 
    if (!g_asWeather.hasOwnProperty(location)) continue;

    results += g_asWeather[location] + '\n';
}

$('#results').html(results);
```

I would also recommend updating the DOM outside of your loop, but that's another issue. It's also worth noting that while I'm using "array-like" syntax (square brackets) to access the object, that does not mean that the object is an array or can be treated like one.

JavaScript allows a few different syntaxes for accessing object properties. You can use "dot notation" when you are directly accessing a property by name, or using square brackets when passing the property name as a string. Consider the following example:

```
var foobar = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar'
};

foobar.a; // 'foo'
foobar['a']; // also 'foo'

foobar.forEach(someCallback); // fails because it's not an array
```